# Adding additional powerline adapter

Tags: powerline-networking

My current setting is like this:

```
router<->powerline adapter 1 (from ActionTec)

xbox<->powerline adapter 2
```

Now, I want to connect VoIP phone using powerline adapter. Can I simply do the following?

```
VoIP phone <-> powerline adapter 3
```

Or I need to do this? (pair 1 and 2):

```
router<->powerline adapter 1 
router<->powerline adapter 3 (connect to another port on the router) 

xbox<->powerline adapter 2
VoIP phone <-> powerline adapter 4
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set up powerline adaptor 3 to the same 'network' as the other two (and if you haven't changed your settings from the defaults, you should). The alternate setup you've suggested is un-necessary